# Scroll View remove subview

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, scrollview, subview

I have a UIScrollView that shows a number of images ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOe7EP4DD3yN0tvNTlKZmdPQzA0WWVPZ25DSDZaaVRHdkk4/view)). I am trying to delete - for example - the third slide, but when I try to to that with this code

```
if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(2) {
    viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

it seems to work since I cannot scroll to that slide anymore, but I can still see it at the bottom as long as I attempt to scroll to it ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOe7EP4DD3yYURUa2pyZmFqRTQ0RHZpOXRBY2hwYUtVXzhz/view?usp=sharing)): as you can see in the video for the last image i am attempting to scroll to it just ricochets back.

I am trying to completely delete that slide from the view, not hiding it :). Any help please would help tons.

Basically just trying to reload/update the view after I delete anyone of the slides.

```
for i in 0..<2 {
    front = UIImageView()

    if let url = URL.init(string: frontImageDisplay[i]) {
        front.downloadedFrom(url: url)
    }
    front.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    let yPosition = self.view.frame.height * CGFloat(i) + self.view.frame.height/2 - (self.view.frame.height / 1.1)/2
    let xPosition = self.view.frame.width/2 - (self.view.frame.width / 1.1)/2
    front.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
    front.layer.borderWidth = 5

    back = UIImageView()

    if let url = URL.init(string: frontImageDisplay[i]) {
        back.downloadedFrom(url: url)
    }

    back.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    back.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
    back.layer.borderWidth = 5

    mainScrollView.contentSize.height = mainScrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(i + 1)

    imageOne.tag = i
    imageTwo.tag = i

    imageOne.addSubview(front)
    imageTwo.addSubview(back)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines of code seem wrong:

```
imageOne.tag = i
imageTwo.tag = i
```

## Preferred Approach:

1. Use a `UIPageViewController` - Read about it and see if it fits your needs before using it.
2. Using auto layout is preferred as it adapts to different screens and orientations and you don't have to do the calculation of frame
3. Don't use tags for identifying the views. Instead keep a model (array) of source images and iterate through them.